# How to read from an Amazon S3 Bucket and call AWS services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-textract

I am able to call AWS Textract to read an image from my local path. How can I integrate this textract code to read the image uploaded onto a created S3 bucket with the S3 bucket codes.

**Working Textract Code to textract images from local path**

```
package aws.cloud.work;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextract;
import com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.textract.model.DetectDocumentTextRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.textract.model.DetectDocumentTextResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.textract.model.Document;
import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;

public class TextractDemo {

    static AmazonTextractClientBuilder clientBuilder = AmazonTextractClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);

    private static FileWriter file;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//AWS Credentials to access AWS Textract services

        clientBuilder.setCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicAWSCredentials("Access Key", "Secret key")));

//Set the path of the image to be textract. Can be configured to use from S3

      String document="C:\\Users\\image-local-path\\sampleTT.jpg";
      ByteBuffer imageBytes;

//Code to use AWS Textract services

        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(document))) {
            imageBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
        }
        AmazonTextract client = clientBuilder.build();
        DetectDocumentTextRequest request = new DetectDocumentTextRequest()
                .withDocument(new Document().withBytes(imageBytes));

        /*
         * DetectDocumentTextResult result = client.detectDocumentText(request);
         * System.out.println(result); result.getBlocks().forEach(block ->{
         * if(block.getBlockType().equals("LINE")) System.out.println("text is "+
         * block.getText() + " confidence is "+ block.getConfidence());
         */ 

//      
        DetectDocumentTextResult result = client.detectDocumentText(request);
        System.out.println(result);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        result.getBlocks().forEach(block -> {
            if (block.getBlockType().equals("LINE"))
                System.out.println("text is " + block.getText() + " confidence is " + block.getConfidence());
            JSONArray fields = new JSONArray();

            fields.add(block.getText() + " , " + block.getConfidence());
            obj.put(block.getText(), fields);

        });

//To import the results into JSON file and output the console output as sample.txt      
        try {
            file = new FileWriter("/Users/output-path/sample.txt");
            file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                file.flush();
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[**This is an example of the console out where the "text" and corresponding "confidence scores" are returned**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0FVy.png)

**S3 bucket code integration I managed to find from the docs:**

```
        String document = "sampleTT.jpg";
        String bucket = "textract-images";

        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration( 
                        new EndpointConfiguration("https://s3.amazonaws.com","us-east-1"))
                .build();
        
               
        // Get the document from S3
        com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object s3object = s3client.getObject(bucket, document);
        S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

---

**(Edited) - Thanks @smac2020, I currently have a working Rekognition Code that reads from my AWS console S3 bucket and runs the Rekognition services that I am referencing to. However, I am unable to modify and merge it with
the Textract source code**

```
package com.amazonaws.samples;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognition;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.AmazonRekognitionException;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.DetectLabelsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.DetectLabelsResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.Image;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.Label;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.S3Object;
import java.util.List;

public class DetectLabels {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String photo = "sampleTT.jpg";
    String bucket = "Textract-bucket";

    
    
//    AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("ap-southeast-1").build();

    AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider (new BasicAWSCredentials("Access Key", "Secret Key"));
    AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentialsProvider).withRegion("ap-southeast-1").build();

    
    DetectLabelsRequest request = new DetectLabelsRequest()
         .withImage(new Image()
         .withS3Object(new S3Object()
         .withName(photo).withBucket(bucket)))
         .withMaxLabels(10)
         .withMinConfidence(75F);

    try {
       DetectLabelsResult result = rekognitionClient.detectLabels(request);
       List <Label> labels = result.getLabels();

       System.out.println("Detected labels for " + photo);
       for (Label label: labels) {
          System.out.println(label.getName() + ": " + label.getConfidence().toString());
       }
    } catch(AmazonRekognitionException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You are not referencing the latest example Jave code example for working with the AWS SDK For Java. See examples here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2

Comment: Thanks @smac2020, I currently have a working Rekognition Code that reads from my AWS console S3 bucket and runs the Rekognition services that I am referencing to. However, I am unable to modify and merge it with the Textract source code. Please refer to the **(Edited)** section for the Rekognition Code I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to read an Amazon S3 object from a Spring boot app and then pass that byte array to **DetectDocumentTextRequest**.

There is a tutorial that shows a very similar use case where a Spring BOOT app reads the bytes from an Amazon S3 object and passes it to the Amazon Rekognition service (instead of Textract).

The Java code is:

```
// Get the byte[] from this AWS S3 object.
public byte[] getObjectBytes (String bucketName, String keyName) {

    s3 = getClient();

    try {
        GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();
        
        ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
        byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();
        return data;

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

See this AWS development article to see how to build a Spring BOOT app that has this functionality.

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

This example uses the **AWS SDK For Java V2**. If you are not familiar with working with the latest SDK version, I recommend that you start here:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

Comment: Thanks @smac2020 for the references and help. I am trying to keep my source code in a single java class like the Rekognition Code I have just added below in my main post. I am trying to integrate this piece of code in:

**AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration("https://s3.amazonaws.com","us-east-1")).build();
             
      // Get the document from S3
      com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object s3object = s3client.getObject(bucket, document);
      S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();**